# OpenGL with Delphi: Offscreen Rendering of an Image to File

Tags: delphi, opengl, bitmap, framebuffer

I need some help regarding saving the rendered contents of OpenGL's ViewPort to a bitmap file, in Delphi XE2.

Basically the thing that I want to do is after some rendering has been done, dump the contents of the FrameBuffer to a bitmap (full color format) file. Here is the excerpt of code that is supposed to accomplish this.

```
 procedure TForm1.saveBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
      var
      //TBitmap object holding the newly created Bitmap.  
        srcBitmap: TBitmap;
      // the array to hold pixels value while reading from the FrameBuffer
        pixels: Array of GLUbyte;
        dimensions: Array [0 .. 3] of Integer;
      //Stream between the memory location of pixels and my bitmap.
        MS: TMemoryStream;
        I: Integer;
      begin
         if SaveDialog1.Execute then
         begin
      //create the bitmap and set it to Full Color Format; Open the Memory Stream
        srcBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
        srcBitmap.PixelFormat:=pf24bit;
        MS:= TMemoryStream.Create;
      //get the dimensions info for the current ViewPort
        glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, @dimensions);
        srcBitmap.Width := dimensions[2];
        srcBitmap.Height :=dimensions[3];
      //allocate enough memory for pixels;
        SetLength(pixels, dimensions[2] * dimensions[3] * 3);

      //this is the function that is supposed to read the contents from the Frame 
      // Buffer and write them to pixels
        glReadPixels(0, 0, dimensions[2], dimensions[3], GL_RGB,
          GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, @pixels);

      //Do something if an error occured
        ErrorHandler;

      // Below I attempt to create a bitmap file from the read in pixels
        MS.Read(pixels,dimensions[2] * dimensions[3] * 3) ;
        srcBitmap.LoadFromStream(MS);
        Edit2.Text := SaveDialog1.FileName;
        srcBitmap.SaveToFile(Edit2.Text);
        MS.Free;
        srcBitmap.Free;
        end;
 end;
```

The main problems I encounter are:

1) Stack Overflow error if the ViewPort size is too big ( i get SO error trying to save images with size 256*256).I think this might be because the 'glReadPixels' function reads the FrameBuffer onto the PROCESSOR MEMORY( I assume this to be L2 Cache), not the main memory, and this one cannot fit the whole image inside. Is this the case? If so, do you have any idea about how do I read the FrameBuffer onto the MAIN MEMORY?

2) Testing on smaller viewports (25x25), in order to avoid the error in 1), gives me an Access Violation Error, when I try to access any of the values stored in 'pixels' array. This means that the glReadPixels does not read from the buffer properly, and I believe that the reason for this is some inconsistency between with the parameters I am passing to the function `glReadPixels(0, 0, dimensions[2], dimensions[3], GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, @pixels)` .

Comment: How did you create your OpenGL context? Hidden window + FBO or PBuffer?

Comment: Well I did the default context initialization using 
  DC := GetDC(panelHandle);
  RC := CreateRenderingContext(DC, [opDoubleBuffered], 32, 24, 0, 0,       0, 0);
  ActivateRenderingContext(DC, RC)

Answer (score 2):

```
Procedure GetOGL_BMP(var BMP: TBitmap);
var
  Dimensions: array [0 .. 3] of Integer;
  RGBBits: PRGBQuad;
  Pixel: PRGBQuad;
  Header: PBitmapInfo;
  x, y: Integer;
  Temp: Byte;
begin
  glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, @Dimensions);
  GetMem(RGBBits, Dimensions[2] * Dimensions[3] * 4);
  glFinish;
  glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
  glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);
  glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
  glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);
  glReadPixels(0, 0, Dimensions[2], Dimensions[3], GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    RGBBits);
  if not Assigned(BMP) then
      BMP := TBitmap.Create;
  BMP.PixelFormat := pf32Bit;
  BMP.Width := Dimensions[2];
  BMP.Height := Dimensions[3];
  GetMem(Header, SizeOf(TBitmapInfoHeader));
  with Header^.bmiHeader do
  begin
    biSize := SizeOf(TBitmapInfoHeader);
    biWidth := Dimensions[2];
    biHeight := Dimensions[3];
    biPlanes := 1;
    biBitCount := 32;
    biCompression := BI_RGB;
    biSizeImage := Dimensions[2] * Dimensions[3] * 4;
  end;
  // Rot und Blau vertauschen
  Pixel := RGBBits;
  for x := 0 to Dimensions[2] - 1 do
    for y := 0 to Dimensions[3] - 1 do
    begin
      Temp := Pixel.rgbRed;
      Pixel.rgbRed := Pixel.rgbBlue;
      Pixel.rgbBlue := Temp;
      inc(Pixel);
    end;
  SetDIBits(BMP.Canvas.Handle, BMP.Handle, 0, Dimensions[3], RGBBits,
    TBitmapInfo(Header^), DIB_RGB_COLORS);

  FreeMem(Header);
  FreeMem(RGBBits);
end;
```

Comment: @Bummi By the way, read pixels with parameter `GL_BGRA`, so you won't need to swap the RGB bits later, saving the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

**First**: you Read from the stream instead of writing to it:
MS.**Read**(pixels,dimensions[2] * dimensions[3] * 3) ;

**Second**: pixels is a dynamic array, which essentially is a pointer to that array. To get a pointer to the first byte use @pixels[0] in glReadPixels and for writing into the memory stream.